# Can any one help me how to do the following in Javascript (2).add(3)(4)(5)...?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I need to add numbers like 2+3+4+5+...  I was asked to do this using Prototypes  Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Read about `currying` in javascript

Comment: Even using Currying, how do you add (2) to remaining numbers?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.This isn't a homework resource for you, please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you really are stuck, describe some things you've attempted and what isn't working

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you mean :

```
Number.prototype.add = function(number){
    return this.valueOf() + number
}
```

Usage :

`(2).add(3) //5`

`(2).add(3).add(4) //9`

---

If you want curry:

```
Number.prototype.curry = function(end){
    if (end <= this.valueOf()) {
        throw "End must be larger."
    } else {
        return (this.valueOf() + end) * (1 - this.valueOf() + end / 2
    }
}
```

Usage:

`(2).curry(5) //equivalent to 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 14`